# Setting the page title in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the below code and which makes the page title more seo friendly.  However I am running into the below problems.

```
config.noPageTitle = 1
    page.headerData {
      100 = TEXT
      100 {
        field = description
        noTrimWrap = noTrimWrap = |<title>| - Example Site</title>|
    }
}
```

If I have the field = title it displays tha page title field, however on the news single page it doesn't work as it displays the name of the page rather than the title of the aritle.

If I have the field = description the news single defaults to the article title however  if I haven't put a description on one of my pages then it displays

```
 <title> - Example Site</title>
```

Is there away to do if description = '' show title (if it is not a news article)?
Or is there another way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many samples and snippets for using tt_news title as page title.

Check for an instance this one: http://blog.chandanweb.com/typo3/display-news-title-as-page-title-in-tt_news-detail-view

Comment: I hadn't come across this site before thanks, it was very helpful.